# How do I query DataDog for a phrase in the stack trace?

Tags: datadog

DataDog is so useless in its querying and its intuitiveness ... I'm looking for a custom exception in the stack trace. I found individual log entries in the last 18 hours that contain my exception class name, but attempting to write a log query that will find me all the occurrences is returning nothing. E.g.:

environment:prod @thrown.extendedStackTrace:UserDoesNotExistException

I'd like to include more words in the query, but even reducing down a single word fails to find anything. I've looked at their documentation, which is zero help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked for me (where my stacktrace is in a `stack_trace` attribute) after reading the [doco](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/#search-wildcard) and trial and error:

`@stack_trace:*the?quick?brown?fox*`

i.e. to search on a phrase (multiple words), don't use quotes (so leading/trailing wildcards work) and replace spaces with `?`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding wildcards on either side of your search query.

For example:

```
environment:prod @thrown.extendedStackTrace:*UserDoesNotExistException*
```

Make sure the query value itself (i.e. the value after the colon) isn't wrapped in quotes, as wildcards do not work within quotes since it would be read as a string literal.